# Docker: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file which sets up a service with a GitHub URL for the context.  The service's Dockerfile copies a `requirements.txt` and installs it.  That works OK (`COPY requirements.txt /rasa_traind/`).  But when I change that line to `COPY . <dir>` I get a `COPY failed: file not found in build context` error.

Docker Compose

```
  chatbot_server:
    build:
      context: <GitHub URL>
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    depends_on:
      - rasa_actions_server
      - redis
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" # for docker.host.internal to work on Linux
```

docker-compose build

```
Step 4/8 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5a584d36ea77
Step 5/8 : COPY . /rasa_traind/
ERROR: Service 'chatbot_server' failed to build: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat rasa_traind/: file does not exist
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.12-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update

RUN yes | apt-get install python3-dev build-essential

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# COPY requirements.txt /rasa_traind/ # Works
COPY . /rasa_traind/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /rasa_traind/rasa_actions_server/

CMD ["rasa", "run"]
```

Comment: Could you try the array syntax, eg `COPY [".", "/rasa_traind/"]`?

Comment: Could it be that the directory you try to copy to does not exist? Have you tried `RUN mkdir /rasa_traind` before the `COPY` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @st.huber you don't need to create target directories before `COPY`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the WORKDIR before COPY . /rasa_traind/. Something like this

```
FROM python:3.8.12-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update

RUN yes | apt-get install python3-dev build-essential

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /rasa_traind/rasa_actions_server/

# COPY requirements.txt /rasa_traind/ # Works
COPY . /rasa_traind/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["rasa", "run"]
```